# Convert $f(x) = (\cos x+\sin x)(1-\sqrt{3}\tan x)$ into the form of $k(1+\tan x)\cos(x+a).$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I need your help to convert the following into the form of $k(1+\tan(x))\cos(x+a).$

$$f(x) = (\cos(x)+\sin(x))(1-\sqrt{3}\tan x)$$

Here is what I've done so far.

\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= (\cos(x)+\sin(x))(1-\sqrt{3}\tan x)\\
f(x) &= \sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(x)+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin(x))(1-\sqrt{3}\tan x)\\
f(x) &= \sqrt{2}\cos(x-\frac{\pi}{4})(1-\sqrt{3}\tan x)
\end{aligned}

Please help me.

Comment: what is that `k`?

Comment: $K$ and $a$ are the constants that we want to find. Please help

Comment: Try for small angles using Taylor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to find $k$ and $a$ such that

$k(1+\tan x)\cos(x+a)=(\cos x+\sin x)(1-\sqrt3\tan x)$

or

$k(\cos x+\sin x)\dfrac{\cos(x+a)}{\cos x}=(\cos x+\sin x)(1-\sqrt3\tan x)$

or

$k(\cos a-\sin a\tan x)=(1-\sqrt3\tan x).$

Now the similarity is obvious. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could you explain it bit more please?

Comment: @KavinduChamodhNethsara Take a factor $2$ from the right hand side.

Comment: Thanks everyone I solved it with your help.